# Drag-and-Drop file from filesystem to Java web application for IE9

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, filesystems

I need to implement drag and drop functionality like in Google Drive. That is possibility to drag files from file system and drop it to browser window and start file uploading. Is there a way to implement it using Java?
In what way is it implemented in Google Drive and other similar services?

UPD:
There are several jQuery plugins for this but a haven't found no one that works correct with IE9.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Look at the [DnD API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: Do you want it to work in a Java desktop application (i.e. Swing or JavaFX) or in a Web application, based on a Java framework (JSF, Wicket, Struts, whatsoever)?

Comment: I want it to work in Java web application: Spring, jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can use this class named [FileDrop](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/filedrop/) in your Java Applet.

You can attach a FileDrop listener to a JComponent of your applet, such as a JPanel, and when users will drag and drop files onto it, the filesDropped method will be invoked, making available to you the array of files dropped.

```
JPanel  myPanel = new JPanel();
  new  FileDrop( myPanel, new FileDrop.Listener()
  {   public void  filesDropped( java.io.File[] files )
      {   
          // handle file drop
          ...
      }   // end filesDropped
  }); // end FileDrop.Listener
```

Then, you can upload files via ftp, e.g. using the [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) class of the Apache commons-net library, to your ftp server.

Comment: Yes, it is posibble to do with applet. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say about Java, but you can use Javascript/jQuery.

Check out [this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). Of course there are other options, but if you want to use it in your browser, I can't think of an easier way.